# Regex substitution: getting half of the string

Tags: regex, pcre

I got another question about regex. The requirement is quite easy:

Given a string that has length of a even number.

- `12`
- `1234`
- `123456`
- `12345678`
- `abcdef`

Write a substition regex to get the first half of the string:

After substition:

- `1`
- `12`
- `123`
- `1234`
- `abc`

I'm using pcre, it supports recursion and control verbs.

I tried something like this but it's not working :(

```
s/^(?=(.))(?:((?1))(?1))+$/$2/mg
```

Here's [the test subject on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/A7QJvP/1/)

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where did you get this question from? Another quiz?

Comment: Something like this: ``^(?:.(?=.*?((?(1).\1|.)$)))+\K\1``
Replacement - empty string

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is *not* the most elegant solution, but it does work:

```py
>>> def half(string):
        regex = re.compile(r"(.{%d})" % int(len(string)/2))
        return regex.search(string).group(1)

>>> half("12")
'1'
>>> half("1234")
'12'
>>> half("123456")
'123'
>>> half("12345678")
'1234'
>>> half("abcdef")
'abc'
```

Comment: It works but I'm not allowed to use any code, only one regex is allowed :(